# Redirecting to action in ASP.NET MVC, method wont return the view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery post method for executing a server side action

the method is :

```
 function redirectToDraft() {

    updateInboxGridAndCloseApproveDialog();
    $.post('/Personnel/AgendaApproveDocument');
  }
```

it will post to this action and then in the action i need to redirect to another action on the other controller like this :

```
 public ActionResult AgendaApproveDocument(int? id){

     return RedirectToAction("RelatedDocumentDraft",  new RouteValueDictionary(
                new
                {
                    controller = "RegisterLetter",
                    action = "RelatedDocumentDraft",
                    title = relatedDoc.Name,
                    factory = relatedDoc.DocumentFactory,
                    activityId = action.WorkItem.Id
                }));

}
```

it works and redirect to the method:

```
 public ActionResult RelatedDocumentDraft(int?activityId, string factory, string title)
    {
    return View("~/Views/RegisterLetter/NewDraft.aspx");
    }
```

my problem is that it doesnt return to the view "NewDraft"

is there any thing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see if you view can actually be found at that location?

Comment: So what page has it been re-directed? Or what response you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your AJAX call you haven't subscribed to the success callback, so nothing will happen. If you wanted to handle the results of an AJAX call, that's what you should do:

```
$.post('/Personnel/AgendaApproveDocument', function(result) {
    // the result variable here will contain the markup of the view    
    // so you could for example replace some portion of the DOM with it
    // (assuming of course it is a partial view):

    $('#foo').html(result);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `RedirectToAction` method. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546461/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-a-different-view) from John Sheehan.

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
```

Additional information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction.aspx).

Comment: if u read my post completely u would see that my problem is that the method which i redirect to wont return the view

Answer (score 1):

You're doing an AJAX post to this method - it won't do anything with the response unless you tell it to.  Why the AJAX, would a simple form submit work better?