# Need to redirect to another page in asp.net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm working with ASP.net and MVC3 . I need to show a popup or go to the login page When the session get expired. Can any one please tell me How to redirect to login page which is having action name as "index" and the controller name as "Home".

My Code is:

This method is in my model.In this model I have to redirect to login page.

```
protected Product GetCurrentCorp(HttpContextBase context)
    {

        if (context.Session != null)
        {
            var selectedProduct = context.Session["SelectedProduct"];
            if (selectedProduct != null)
            {
                var product= selectedProduct as Product;
                return product;                   
            }
        }
        // Here I need to redirect to index page(login page)
        throw new ArgumentException("Product is not set, Cannot Continue.");
    }
```

Comment: why do you access HttpContext and Session inside of the model?

Comment: You don't redirect from your model, you need to do this in your action method in the controller.

Comment: @nan: In this model only I am checking the Authorization of the user credentials. So i need to redirect here only.

Answer (score 4):

If **LoggedOn** is your Action and **Account** is your Controller then you can write your code as:

```
return RedirectToAction("LoggedOn", "Account");
```

Hope this will help you.!!!

Comment: RedirectToAction can access in controller only. I am not able to access in my Model class file. Do we need to add any namespace for access this RedirectToAction method?

Comment: You can not access RedirecToAction mehod in Model Class.

Comment: So can u please tell me How can i redirect from model to login page?

Comment: you are not clear with the Concept of MVC. Please have a look here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/what-is-mvc

Answer (score 3):

Use

[Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

or [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29)

or [RedirectToRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoroute%28v=vs.108%29)

Also refer old post [ASP.Net MVC Redirect To A Different View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546461/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-a-different-view)

Comment: Basically your controller is the responsible for Redirect. Model is not supposed to do that.

Comment: So how can we access this in model? can you please give me some advise on this?

Comment: Simple call the model from controller and check the returned product in controller. If returned product from model is null in controller then use RedirectToAction

Answer (score 2):

This is the self contained action that is showing you examples of redirection to different action or URL.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  // Use this for action, can also be used to redirect 
  // to action on different controller by adding parameter
  return RedirectToAction("MyActionName");

  // Use this for URL
  return Redirect("http://example.com/foo/bar");
}
```

Hope this is of help to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RedirectToAction()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470594(v=vs.108).aspx)

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

Comment: In Model we can't access the RedirectToAction(). Is it possible by any other way?