# Redirect to other page (asp.net mvc 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code in controller

```
public ActionResult WhatWeDo()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

but I need to create redirect to other page.
How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC Redirect To A Different View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546461/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-a-different-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the RedirectToAction method.

```
RedirectToAction("action", "controller")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just

```
return Redirect("http://www.google.com");
```

Hope it helps