# Redirect To a different view is not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

[image]

I am trying to redirect to a different view (ApartmentController) ,
so I have tried all the methods mentioned here :[RedirectToAnOtherView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546461/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-a-different-view)
But none worked with me ,
Any help  would be thankfull
My Controller is ApartmentController
my View Is Index so My url would be like "Apartment/Index"
I have tried :

```
return RedirectToAction("/Apartment/Index",new Apartment());
return View("Apartment");
return RedirectToActionPermanent("Apartment");
```

none worked with me

Comment: are you doing ajax? what's the client code look like?

Comment: yes it is ajax request

Comment: "none worked with me". So what actually happens?

Comment: @ColinM it does not redirect to apartment/index

Comment: ajax won't redirect the browser, it only redirects that request.

Comment: @DanielA.White So what is the solution ? what i should do like a work around

Comment: Perform the redirect on the client side

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: @ColinM  you mean like window.location.href="apartment/index"??

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong then you're attempting path in same controller then please try this, it should be work:

> return RedirectToAction("Index");
>
> return RedirectToAction("Apartment", "Index");

If you are redirect one controller to another controller action then try this:

> return RedirectToAction("yourAnotherActionName","yourAnotherControllerName");