# Call a Javascript form within a controller in MVC4

Tags: javascript, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to call a javascript function from within a controller function that I use:

```
 Public Function redirectTo() As JavaScriptResult
        Return JavaScript("ToSignUp()")
    End Function
```

in my controller. But the program never goes to the script.  I've already checked similar answers but I haven't found any solution to the problem.  Can someone assist me with this?

**ADDITION 4/3/19 12:41**
I use the following for redirection from my controller... but nothing is happening:

```
Public Function redirectTo() As RedirectToRouteResult
        Dim routes As New RouteCollection With {.RouteExistingFiles = True}
        Return RedirectToAction("../login/SignUp")
    End Function
End Class
```

**ADDITION 4/3/19 23:20**
The issue was solved by this way
In the `code behind` of my `.aspx` Page and at the proper place I add it the following code:

```
 Dim routes As New RouteCollection With {.RouteExistingFiles = True}
  Response.Redirect("SignUp")
```

The `Response.Redirect` instruction is not new. 
But in order to be functional it needs to add before the following instruction

```
Dim routes As New RouteCollection With {.RouteExistingFiles = True}
```

And that is because the MVC did not recognize the existent files which means the property `RouteExistingFiles` is always `False` 
Thus in order to work the code we need to turn this property to `True`
Anyway thanks to all for your assistance.

Comment: You can't "call" javascript form the server they run in totally separate spheres. You can write some output to your view that will trigger javascript once the vire loads. I don't know vb.net but I'd imagine `Javascript` actually returns JSON which is a information exchange format. It's not executed

Comment: This question can't be answered without some additional information on when and how you want your JS to fire, etc.

Comment: Well the main Idea doing that was to redirect from the page that I work, into another page, which is in the same directory.

Comment: So why don't you just return a `Redirect`?

Comment: What exactly mean by that? RedirectToAction?? Or??

Comment: Redirecting to another page has nothing to do with javascript :) Just use Redirect or RedirectToAction and provide it with url (a path to the destination page).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC Redirect To A Different View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546461/asp-net-mvc-redirect-to-a-different-view)

Comment: "the main Idea doing that was to redirect from the page that I work, into another page"...agreed, JavaScript is definitely not needed for this.

Comment: Please have a look in my addition

Comment: How do you call this action? `Redirect` just issues a HTTP 302. If your using ajax or something then this won't be honoured by the calling code.

Comment: From my codebehind using `Attributes.loginPageController.redirectTo()`. In an other case I use `ajax` and works fine, that was the reason I want to use `javascript`

Comment: I don't really know what your asking anymore. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: Yes I'll delete this an re-post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From other examples online ([like this one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/db2972/javascript-result-in-controller-sample-in-mvc-day-12/)), I would say that if you temporarily changed your function to:

```
Public Function redirectTo() As JavaScriptResult
    Return JavaScript("alert("HERE");")
End Function
```

It will likely work...  so without seeing the JS function contents, it's hard to tell.  To the second point, a `RedirectToAction` call will work if called from the server; if the client is calling this, use 'window.location' instead.

Comment: I Use ` Public Function callScript() As JavaScriptResult
            Return JavaScript("alert('ToSignUp()');")
        End Function` In order to call the script. But didn't work, did not pass thru the script... any suggestion?

Comment: Are you sure the routing is occurring correctly then?  If you open up the network tab, is it returning 404 possibly?

Comment: Are you referring in my solution or in my notice above? And what did you mean 404? the error or something?

Comment: I'm referring to whatever is requesting the "redirectTo" action; if it's not routing correctly, it could yield a 404 or 500 error, for instance...  Using the debugging tools would help identify that.

Comment: Yes.. OK at first this error was threw from the `redirectToRoute` but from the moment I add the `RouteExistingFiles` property to true then the error stop but nothing happen (I mean there was never redirect to anywhere) so I stop use the route (in general).

Comment: Now about my routing table I have (except of the default) this record as well `routes.MapRoute(
           name:="SignUp",
           url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults:=New With {.controller = "login", .action = "SignUp", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
       )` But except from the first record nothing else it works. Or rather I don't know how to make it work